# How do we set credentials on TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am able to create a Team Project Collection on TFS Server. I am also able to add projects to the same using Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2013 ultimate edition). But how do I create/set login credentials for the projects (I do not want users of one project to try accessing the other projects in the same collection).

Answer (score 0):

By default, only administrators will have access to a team project. You can add team members from the web portal by clicking "Manage" next to "Members", or by clicking on the "Settings" gear in the top right and navigating to the "Security" tab.